# Dimension of biggest linear subspace inside a variety of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry

A variety of matrices (or algebraic set) $V$ is a set of matrices over a field $F$ which are the common zeros of a set of polynomials (on their entries). Some varieties contain linear subspaces of matrices, and others do not. Examples:

- Every linear subspace is a variety.
- If $0\not\in V$ then there is no linear subspace inside $V$.
- If $\det(A)=0$ then $\det(\lambda A)=0$ for all $\lambda\in F$.
- If $V$ is the variety of $\det$ on $\text{Mat}_n(F)$ and $L$ denotes the subspace of all matrices whose first row is full of zeros, then $L\subseteq V$ and $\dim_F L=n^2-n$.

Given a variety $V$ inside $\text{Mat}_{m\times n}(F)$, define
$$\text{ldim}(V):=\max\{\dim L \ | \ L\leq\text{Mat}_{m\times n}(F), L\subseteq V\}$$

and ldim$(V)=-1$ if there is no such $L$ (iff $0\not\in V$).

My questions are the following:

1) Given $V$, what tools do we have to find ldim$(V)$?

2) What do we know when $V$ are the determinantal varieties (those of matrices with rank no greater than a fixed $k$)?

3) Given $\text{Mat}_{m\times n}(F)$, what is the maximum ldim possible for varieties which are not subspaces themselves, and for which varieties is it attained? For square matrices, is it $n^2-n$ as in the third example?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your questions, but you might find this paper useful: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1689267

Comment: Nice question. But does it matter that we think about matrices? Maybe this is distracting. Your definitions work as well for any algebraic set $A \subset F^n$.

Comment: @red_trumpet Indeed, you are right, it could be that the answers are easier in the more general setting (perhaps someone knows some general theorem about this?). But I hope that, given the additional structure of matrix rings (rank, matrix groups, symmetric functions, etc.) this may have already been developed in the literature; I know of similar results (like if a subspace has an element of rank greater than k, then it must have dimension greater than nk). Another reason is that these questions have some relevance to linear preserver problems, a subject in which I'm interested in.